# Accessing WCF service through internet

Tags: wcf

I have created and deployed a wcf service on iis. I am able to access the service in intranet , what else should i do to expose my service in internet??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a number of questions you need to ask yourself:

- how and where do you plan to host your service (IIS? Self-hosting)?
- what protocol / binding are you going to use? basicHttp is the easiest, but also the most limited - it doesn't support much security, no reliable sessions etc., but its interoperability with other systems is its big advantage
- or do you want to expose a REST service, so that your users will just get XML or JSON back?
- what kind of security do you need? Transport-level? Message-level?
- will you authenticate your users? How? Windows credentials? Certificates? Username/password? Not at all?
- where (what address and port) will you publicly make your service available?
- if you use a SOAP-based approach: how are potential clients going to know about this service? Do you want to make the metadata (WSDL, XSD) available online (at the `xxxx?wsdl` address)? Do you want to ship the explicit metadata as files to your clients? Will you create a WCF client proxy class yourself and make that assembly available for download?

Once you have all the answer, everything should be clear :-)

Marc

Comment: Thanks marc for your guidance.